# Swift: UIPanGesture on tableview cell not working

Tags: swift

Heyy,
Hello I want to implement a gesture in a tableview cell but it does not work here is my code:

```
var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer?


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(detectPan(recognizer:)))
    panGesture?.delaysTouchesBegan = false
    panGesture?.delaysTouchesEnded = false
    separatorView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture!)
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@objc func detectPan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.vc?.view)

    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:
        self.startingConstant = self.constantCenter.constant
    case .changed:
        self.constantCenter.constant = self.startingConstant + translation.x
    case .ended:
        if translation.x > 0 {
            constantCenter.isActive = false
            constanteGauche.isActive = false
            constanteDroite.isActive = true
        }else{
            constantCenter.isActive = false
            constanteGauche.isActive = true
            constanteDroite.isActive = false
            print("ok")
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.vc?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

        constantCenter.constant = separatorView.center.x - (self.vc?.view.center.x)!
        constantCenter.isActive = true
        constanteGauche.isActive = true
        constanteDroite.isActive = true
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Do I have to fix something in my function tableview:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //On lien le TableViewCell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? FeedCell
    cell?.selectionStyle = .none

    cell?.vc = self
    cell?.delegate = self

    cell?.view(post: FeedPostController.posts[indexPath.row], user: FeedPostController.users[indexPath.row]); //On passe l'objet a l'index i a la fonction view du TableViewCell pour l'affichage

    return cell!;
}
```

I tried a lot of possibilities but nothing works, the function of the gesture I need it in the uitableviewcell because I use constraints that are in the cell

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()


    separatorView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true //THIS LINE ITS VERY IMPORTANT !!!!!!!!
    panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(detectPan(recognizer:)))
    panGesture?.delaysTouchesBegan = false
    panGesture?.delaysTouchesEnded = false
    separatorView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture!)
}
```

Comment: is the separatorView large enough for a user to actually touch on it and perform a pan gesture ? Why don't you try a pan gesture on a simple view in a separate project and see if things are ok first

Comment: In separator project its work fine, i must to implement it to tableview cell now..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code example. 100% works. Hope, it'll help.

```
import UIKit

private let cellID = "cellID"

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  // Setup Table View
  private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let rect: CGRect = view.bounds
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: rect, style: .grouped)
    tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
    tableView.backgroundColor = .white
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    // If you need to PAN the tableView, uncomment this line
    // tableView.addGestureRecognizer(self.panGesture)
    return tableView
  }()

  // Setup panGesture
  private lazy var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPan(sender:)))
    // Set delegate 
    pan.delegate = self
    return pan
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(tableView)
  } 

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .red

    // Add panGesture to first cell for example
    if indexPath.section == 0, indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(self.panGesture)
        cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        cell.textLabel?.text = "You can drag a table for this cell"
    }

    return cell
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

}

extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

  @objc fileprivate func didPan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
      let translation = sender.translation(in: view)

      switch sender.state {
      case .began:
          print("Began")
      case .changed:
          print("Canged \(translation.y)")
          // This is just example to show you how that works. Dragging tableView.
          tableView.frame.origin.y = translation.y
      case .ended:
          print("Ended")
      default:
          break
      }
  }

}
```

Link for short video how it works on device: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lorvamynbwvyv7/TJCQ1216.MP4?dl=0

If you have any questions, just ask )

Comment: Little bit later I will send here a detailed code example.. I'm at work now :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm waiting for you :)

Comment: I still have not found a solution, I hope you have not forgotten me :)

Comment: I've sent an answer to you.